# Pthread identifying number increases and causes loop to not perform properly

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

EDIT: I fixed the issue by getting rid of the structure and passing in a copy of the loop parameter.

```
 //The struct that gets passed in to threadsafe function
 struct threading_struct {
    cell *cellMatrix;
    int thread_number;
 };

 //WHERE BELOW VOID IS CALLED FROM
 do {
    pthread_t threads[num_Threads];
    void *th_status;
    thread_part = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_Threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, dissipate_cell, (void*) &threading_info);
    }



 void* name_of_function(void* args) {
     struct threading_struct *arg_struct = (struct threading_struct*) args;
     int ending = 0;
     threading_info.thread_number = thread_part++; //thread_part is a global variable

     if(offStride && arg_struct->thread_number == num_Threads - 1) {
         ending = (arg_struct->thread_number+1)*stride + info.numBoxes % num_Threads;
     } else {
         ending = (arg_struct->thread_number+1)*stride;
     }


     for(int i = arg_struct->thread_number*stride; i < ending; i++) {
```

OUTPUT:

```
 "Thread number: 0  Tn 2: 0  i: 0
 "Thread number: 2  Tn 2: 2  i: 6
 "Thread number: 2  Tn 2: 2  i: 7
 "Thread number: 2  Tn 2: 2  i: 8
 "Thread number: 2  Tn 2: 2  i: 1
 "Thread number: 2  Tn 2: 2  i: 2
 "Thread number: 1  Tn 2: 1  i: 3
 "Thread number: 2  Tn 2: 2  i: 4
 "Thread number: 2  Tn 2: 2  i: 5
```

As you see, thread number 2 gets used a lot while thread number 1 and 0 only get used once. I am trying to get each thread to be used an equal amount of times with the last threads index adding numboxes % numthreads if numthreads does not divide evenly in to numboxes. Is there something that I am doing incorrectly? My program gives me the correct answer, but each thread is not being utilized to its full potential. Is it an issue with thread_part being a global variable? My thinking was that once the thread safe function was entered with thread_part = 0, 1, or 2 then it would stay as that number until the end even if the global variable changed. Maybe my thinking is incorrect in this regard?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit your code to be a [mcve], so that we can compile, edit and test.

Comment: Are you passing the address of the **same** `threading_info` object to every thread in `pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, dissipate_cell, (void*) &threading_info);`?  (And there's no need to cast to/from `void *` in C)

Comment: Each thread needs its own `threading_info` otherwise they're all sharing the same value, which probably changes (though it isn't clear from the code shown).  You don't actually show what `threading_info` is, but neither do you show it being different for each thread.

Comment: Your code minimization is too extreme.  You don't show a complete `do { … } while (…)` loop.  You don't show a complete function.  It isn't clear how `name_of_function()` relates to `dissipate_cell()`.

Comment: Ah yes, it's probably the same threading_info struct for each thread. Thank you, I'll make some edits and see if it helps.

Comment: I was hoping that I could just increment an index of the thread somehow instead of creating a new struct for each thread as the array within the structure can get quite large.